# column having maximum integer value from table sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This query returns me the maximum integer value from a table:

```
  SELECT rownum, max(col) as maxValue -- min 10717 , max = 311216
 FROM
  (
   SELECT rownum, col FROM Tables1
    UNPIVOT
   (col FOR ListofColumns IN 

  (col1,col2,col3,col4,col5, col6))
   AS unpivott) AS p
GROUP BY rownum
```

Instead of "col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6". I would like to make this dynamic(automatically taken from table having data type int/numeric).

Note: Sometimes number of columns could be 50 and I don't want to write each and every column names.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add here the table structure for the mentioned table?

Comment: Table structure can be any thing: I can gety it like this: FROM      INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE     DATA_TYPE IN ( 'numeric')

Comment: to implement my script into your example we need table structure.and some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic sql is the only way.
you start like this,

```
    create  table t1(rolname varchar(20),col1 int,col2 int,col3 int,col4 int)
insert into t1 values('a',32,45,23,645)
,('b',67,34,2673,344),('c',423,767,54,343),('d',676,43435,3432,4343)


declare @col varchar(2000)
select top 1
@col=stuff((select ','+'['+COLUMN_NAME+']' from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS b
where TABLE_NAME=a.TABLE_NAME and  DATA_TYPE='int'  for XML path('') ),1,1,'')
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS a
where TABLE_NAME='t1'

select @col

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='sELECT rolname, max(col)col
 FROM
  (
   SELECT * FROM t1
    UNPIVOT
   (col FOR ListofColumns IN 

  ( '+@col+'))
   AS unpivott) AS p
   GROUP BY rolname'

   exec (@sql)
```

Comment: This will only give the column names But not the column having minimum or max value

Comment: no you did'yt get it. you can start with my script,then further use your script and make it dynamic sql.

Comment: @TryingBest, check my script.it work fine in my local

Comment: Its showing error: The type of column "RoleName" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list. I have "RoleName", "Description","TaskMask" are of type "nvarchar". Here, I'm only trying to find out max and min value of number or integer data type. Any clue?

Comment: @TryingBest ,check my script now.i got your real problem.But for that,provide sample data and table structure

Comment: I'm trying to write a query which will search in the entire INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142558/discussion-between-kumarharsh-and-tryingbest).