# Type of column " " conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written this query to dynamically find the max or min of numeric value from the entire tables. My query goes like this:

```
declare @col varchar(2000)

 set @col = STUFF( (select ',' +' [' + c.name + ']'  FROM  
    sys.columns c
  INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
 WHERE
   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('JRR_20170301_Stg')
   and c.system_type_id = 108 for XML path('')),1,1, '')

   select @col -- This returns the column name and good.

 --However, the problem starts from here below
  declare @sql varchar(max)

 set @sql='SELECT  max(col) 
 FROM JRR_20170301_Stg unPIVOT (col for ListofColumns in ('+@col+')) as unpivat'

   exec (@sql)
```

Here is my table structure:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[JRR_20170301_Stg](
[col1] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[col2] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[col3] [varchar](30) NULL,
[TIMESTAMP1] [varchar](8) NULL,
[BRANCH] [varchar](2) NULL,
[COE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[SCHEME] [varchar](3) NULL,
[NO] [varchar](7) NULL,
[PLAN] [varchar](5) NULL,
[ACODE] [varchar](8) NULL,
[ACTNAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
[SRNAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
[OTHERNAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
[ACTWTCH] [varchar](1) NULL,
[EMPLC] [varchar](5) NULL,
[EMPLNO] [varchar](13) NULL,
[LADATE] [numeric](7, 0) NULL,
[EARN] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
[REGPA] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
[OTAMT] [numeric](7, 2) NULL,
[EMPSTAT] [varchar](1) NULL,
[RESVE5] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Is there any way to correct this error and get the desired result? Can I use cross apply or something?

Comment: i just answered your question in this link.and it will work 100%.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43585733/column-having-maximum-integer-value-from-table-sql-server/43585985?noredirect=1#comment74252698_43585985

Answer (score 1):

For use `unpivat` all fields should be the same type. You need to use `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions to make it.

```
declare @col varchar(2000)
declare @colCAST varchar(4000)

 set @colCAST = STUFF( (select ',' +' CAST([' + c.name + '] AS numeric(7, 2)) AS [' + c.name + ']'  FROM  
    sys.columns c
  INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
 WHERE
   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('JRR_20170301_Stg')
   and c.system_type_id = 108 for XML path('')),1,1, '')

 set @col = STUFF( (select ',' +' [' + c.name + ']'  FROM  
    sys.columns c
  INNER JOIN 
    sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
 WHERE
   c.object_id = OBJECT_ID('JRR_20170301_Stg')
   and c.system_type_id = 108 for XML path('')),1,1, '')

   select @col, @colCAST -- This returns the column name and good.

 --However, the problem starts from here below
  declare @sql varchar(max)

 set @sql='SELECT  max(col) 
 FROM 
 ( 
 SELECT ' + @colCAST + '
 FROM JRR_20170301_Stg
 ) s
  unPIVOT (col for ListofColumns in ('+@col+')) as unpivat'

   exec (@sql)
```